# Can't make api key - node.js steamcommunity

Tags: node.js, bots, steam

When i try to login to my bot, it login but i always got the same error: Can't make api key. What is wrong with this code? I have set api key on bot's account.

```
function login(err, sessionID, cookies, steamguard) {
if(err) {
    logger.error('Auth error');
    logger.debug(err);
    if(err.message == "SteamGuardMobile") {
        account.twoFactorCode = SteamTotp.generateAuthCode(account.shared_secret);
        logger.warn('Error in auth: '+account.twoFactorCode);
        setTimeout(function() {
            community.login(account, login);
        }, 5000);
        return;
    }
    process.exit(0);
}
logger.trace('Sucesfully auth');
account.sessionID = sessionID;
account.cookies = cookies;
community.getWebApiKey('there_is_my_vps_ip', webApiKey);
community.startConfirmationChecker(10000, account.identity_secret);
}

function webApiKey(err, key) {
    if(err) {
        logger.error('Cant make api key');
        logger.debug(err);
        process.exit(0);
        return;
    }
    account.key = key;
    logger.trace('API key bot '+account.accountName+' '+account.key);
    offersSetup();
    community.loggedIn(checkLoggedIn);
}
```

I waited 2 days. I tried login, and I got the same  Error.

```
LOG
[2016-06-26 09:26:36.075] [INFO] [default] - DB connection ID: 107
[2016-06-26 09:26:36.089] [TRACE] [default] - We got account info
[2016-06-26 09:26:36.091] [DEBUG] [default] - RowDataPacket {
  id: 1,
  online: 0,
  name: 'my_name',
  steamid: 'my_steamid',
  shared_secret: 'my_secret',
  identity_secret: 'my_identity',
  accountName: 'my_login',
  password: 'my_pass',
  steamguard: '',
 email_login: '',
  email_password: '',
  twoFactorCode: 'my_2fc',
  auth: true }
[2016-06-26 09:26:37.602] [TRACE] [default] - Sucesfully auth
[2016-06-26 09:26:48.531] [ERROR] [default] - Cant make apikey
[2016-06-26 09:27:00.649] [DEBUG] [default] - { Error: HTTP error 429
    at SteamCommunity._checkHttpError         (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/steamcommunity/components/http.js:96:9)
    at Request._callback     (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/steamcommunity/components/http.js:50:61)
    at Request.self.callback     (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous>     (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1067:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous>     (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/request/request.js:988:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20) code: 429 }
```

Answer (score 1):

im late, but i believe your problem is that u arent using the api key that belongs to that bot. Add $5 to that acc on steam, then head over to www.steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
next simply enter domain and youll get your key. Goto index.php and replace all of the api keys, to yours. Hope this helps